# Nested form symfony 3

Tags: jquery, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have 2 entity in my symfony application with ManyToOne Relationship

```
class Sprint
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;...
```

And

```
Class Livrable
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\MemberBundle\Entity\Sprint", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $sprint; ....
```

And in my form LivrableType, I have

```
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name')
                ->add('sprint', SprintType::class);
    }
```

Everything goes well when I create a **Livrable** with a **sprint** but, what I need is to allow the user to either choose his sprint if existing and create it if not existing.
Thanks you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mapping form directly to entity, make some kind of DTO (LivrableDTO), which will have Sprint, SprintSelect and SprintCreate properties. This DTO you can map back to your Livrable entity.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I am not sure to understand you, your explanation is very brief for me